# How to enable Azure front door caching for a particular service in monolithic architecture

Tags: azure, url-routing, azure-front-door

I have 3 services in monolithic architecture. They all are served by a single backend pool (kubernetes cluster). I want to enable Azure front door caching for only one of them. How can I do that?

I have tried to achieve the same by creating two routing, one for the service to use cache and another for the rest of the services, but it doesn't cache anything.

```
Routing1:
frontend: /api/*
backend: backendCluster
caching: disabled

Routing2:
frontend: /api/serviceToUseCache
backend: backendCluster
caching: enabled for 1 day
```

However, if I enable caching on Routing1, I see requests from all the services are getting cached.

Comment: Cache is enabled on route level on classic AFD and same for AFD standard/premium also. But on classic, all detailed cache configs are on route level. On std/prm, cache behavior/curation are on rules engine. 
So if we separate the routes for each services and enable caching on a single route, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused because of the Routing1
if cache was enabled on **Routing1**, because of **/api/*** it was cached all the services.

Cache behavior can be configured in Rules Engine. Rules Engine caching configuration will always override the route configuration.  When caching is **enabled**, the cache behavior is different based on the cache behavior value selected.
Work around:

1. Create a **Rules engine configuration** at Front Door level
   [image]
2. Mentioned value with specific service information as mentioned in screenshot. ingore the wildcard services like api/*